# Force my software to use the DLL from a specific location

Tags: c++, windows, dll

have a program that uses my DLL, which is now in the same folder that the software comes from so it automatically uses it.

How can I force my software to search for this specific DLL only in the folder where it is located?

I want to prevent someone from planting their DLLs in my place and thus stealing information from the program. I can verify the DLL by location, but I'm not sure how to prevent the program from taking the DLL from another location.

In other words how to prevent a situation where someone will delete my DLL from the folder of the software and insert its DLL into one of the operating system folders where the programs search for DLL by default and when my program will not find the file in its folder it will start searching it in general places of Windows where the DLL will wait for it That he did

In short my questions are:

A Is there a way to prevent my software from looking for a specific DLL in any folder that is not the folder I'm running?

B What are all the places where the program looks for a DLL in Windows (by default I'll just go over everyone and make sure there are no "gifts")

Thanks

Comment: Use `dlopen()` yourself.

Comment: Or LoadLibrary for Windows API ?

Comment: What stops someone from *replacing* the DLL in your folder, instead of just deleting it?

Comment: The application directory is secured already. If someone can replace a binary in the application directory, they can do far more than you are trying to protect against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't link with the DLL at building time. Instead, you can load the DLL by yourself in your code with the [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) API (or [`LoadLibraryEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx) if you want more control) by giving the exact path of the DLL you want to load.